# List of custom objects as argument with generic method

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I'm using generic methods in Java and I would like to use as argument a List of custom object.

My main class is this:

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> T executeGetRequest(String target, Class<T> resultClass) {

        //MY STUFF
        T result = resultClass.newInstance();
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executeGetRequest("myList", List<myCustomObject>.class); // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

I would like to use as argument a `List<myCustomeObject>`. When I'm using `List.class`, there is no error but I'm not sure that the result will be cast in a `myCustomObject`.

Comment: `new resultClass.newInstance();` is not correct syntax

Comment: Think what you want to achieve, a runtime ( where generics do not exist ) safe generic List, no way this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Code is very broken...

1. `List<myCustomObject>.class` is wrong it can be only `List.class`
2. `List` is an Interface and call of `List.class.newInstance();` will throw an exception anyway
3. Even if you will do code like:

   `List<myCustomClass> myList = new ArrayList();
     Object myResult = executeGetRequest("myList", myList.getClass());`

You will get back `myResult` as instance of `ArrayList` class...

You need to reconsider what do you try to achieve - get back a List of `myCustomClass` objects or new instance of `myCustomClass`

BTW: at Runtime there is a "Type erasure" and there is no way to get what object types are in the `List` from `List` implementation.

In short at Runtime it is always `List<Object>`

Comment: *is no way to get what object types are in the List from List implementation*, of course there is, use `TypeToken`s

Comment: @Eugene TypeToken from where? Google Gson? There is no such thing as TypeToken in JDK at least up to Java 1.8. I did not check higher. Still there is Type erasure: `System.out.println(((Type)new ArrayList<String>().getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getBounds()[0]));` prints  `class java.lang.Object`

Comment: I was not saying in JDK, it's in guava, but of course it relies on jdk code, just that guava makes it a lot easier to use

Answer (score 1):

If you always return a list of items, then use `List<T>` as a return type:

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> List<T> executeGetRequest(String target, Class<T> resultClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        T item = resultClass.newInstance();
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(item);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        executeGetRequest("myList", Foo.class);
    }

    static class Foo {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `Class<T>` argument, along with reflection (i.e. `Class.newInstance()`). Use a `Supplier<T>` instead:

```
public static <T> T executeGetRequest(String target, Supplier<T> factory) {

    // MY STUFF

    T result = factory.get();
    return result;
}
```

Then, invoke it as follows:

```
List<myCustomObject> result = executeGetRequest("myList", () -> new ArrayList<>());
```

You can even use the diamond operator (`<>`) when creating the `ArrayList`, as this is infered from the left hand side by the compiler (i.e. `List<myCustomObject>`).

You can also use a method reference:

```
List<myCustomObject> result = executeGetRequest("myList", ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring:

```java
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
```

and use

```java
executeGetRequest("myList", new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyCustomObject>() {
                });
```

instead of

```java
executeGetRequest("myList", List<myCustomObject>.class);
```